# flutter firebase message notification icon color in android OS dark mode

Tags: android, flutter, colors, notifications, darkmode

I am using Flutter 3.10.4 and also using firebase messaging for push notification.

Android API version is **13.**

The problem is the Icon color is showing well in light mode but the color in android night mode is little downed like pastel color.

I want to set same icon color as light mode and dark mode.

Can flutter or firebase messaging control OS dark mode?

I tried to change color.xml in values-night folder. but this issue is still same.

I set androidManifest and color.xml file like below.

androidManifest.xml

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/robot" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#5E3DEA</color>
</resources>
```

**light mode(well shown as #5E3DEA)**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUmWC.jpg)

**dark mode(shown more lighter)**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC6uP.jpg)

the same notification icon color as light mode at android OS dark mode.